# I want text view inside card view with text view wrapped inside card view,it should not make card view stretchable.

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want my text view inside card view to stretch only to  card view width and fit in multiline based on text length.But what happening it is changing the card view width also. Please find the below layout and try to change the text length.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content
            "
            android:id="@+id/frame1"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="96dp"

                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:maxLines="10"
                    android:text="ejweqfewdawdewasdfewefwsefwsfw"/>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/userResponseView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top"

                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="@drawable/right"
                    />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </FrameLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/line"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/frame2"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:minHeight="96dp"

                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionText5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="answer1"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/frame3"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            >
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="96dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="question2"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </FrameLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/line"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:id="@+id/frame4"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:minHeight="96dp"

                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="answer2"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Will you please attach a screenshot of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your cardview's width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` or give it a fixed size of your preference for Eg: `android:layout_width="20dp"` then textView will not expand beyond cardView's width